# Return Generic Type in a function with Swift (Cannot convert return expression of type...)

Tags: swift, generics

I have a problem with generics in swift. Let's expose my code.

Parsable protocol:

```
protocol Parsable {
    associatedtype T
    var value: String {get set}
    init(value: String)
    func parseString() -> T
}
```

Generic class:

```
class ParsableGeneric<T: Parsable> {
    var value: String
    init(v: String) {
        value = v
    }

    func parse() -> T{
        return T(value: self.value)
    }
}
```

Implementation of Int Type:

```
class ParsableIntNew: ParsableGeneric<IntParse> {}

struct IntParse: Parsable {
    func parseString() -> Int {
        return Int(value)!
    }
    var value: String
    typealias T = Int
}
```

Then I have a function like this, that I want to return a ParsableGeneric Type:

```
func test<T: Parsable>() -> ParsableGeneric<T> {
        let intclass = ParsableIntNew(v: "54")
        let number: Int = intclass.parse().parseString()
        return intclass
    }
```

But I've got an error in the `return intclass` (Cannot convert return expression of type 'ParsableIntNew' to return type 'ParsableGeneric'

Why is this happening. I'm returning the correct value.

Thanks, I hope I find a good solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

Your `test()` function basically promises "I will return a `ParsableGeneric<T>` object for any `T` that is a `Parsable`". However, the implementation only returns a `ParsableIntNew`, i.e. it only works when `T` is `IntParse`.

Imagine what happens when you also have a `BoolParse: Parsable` and the compiler concludes that when you call `test()` that `T` is `BoolParse`. The function would still return a `ParsableGeneric<IntParse>` even though the function return type in this case is `ParsableGeneric<BoolParse>`.

Comment: Hey thm, thanks for your contribution. What do you propose to do in this case? use some enum to wrap the values? what I don't want to do is return Any, because is not type safe.

Comment: You're welcome. What is your `test` function supposed to do?

Comment: I have a map outside of this function, this map call to a function that returns the ParsableGeneric. Then I can call test().parse().parseString() and get the value to transform the array into this generic value. It was working if I return Any in test function and then return test().parse().parseString() directly in the test function

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. What kind of map? What is "the array"? What is it that you're trying to achieve?